# Is it possible to put a user into their existing SMS/Text conversation rather than a compose new message view?

Tags: ios, sms

Right now the only way I know to put the user in the messages app is to open a compose new view and insert the contact info into the recipients field. Is it possible to put them into their existing conversation with that person so that they can see their previous texts with that person?

Comment: I'm not certain but i don't think it is without getting app rejected from app store or jail breaking. I agree it's annoying to have that message view to pop up blank in some apps and im sure if other devs and companies could get around it they would themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up to my own question: this is now possible (default) in iOS7